# Dynamics AX 2012 Foreign Key Constraints

Tags: foreign-key-relationship, axapta, dynamics-ax-2012

Let's say I have two tables:

```
Items
  Property1 (relates to PropertyName)
  Property2 (relates to PropertyName)
Properties
  PropertyName (index, single key alternate)
```

When making a normal relation in Dynamics AX 2012, I get the following Best Practice error: Only foreign key constraints are allowed on this table.

I can create a single key alternate foreign key relation to fix the best practice error.  However, I can only do this for one of the fields.  If I do it for both, I receive a compilation error about duplicate alternate keys.

Is there some way to create normal relations like we used to in AX 2009 without a best practice error?

or.. How can I do two foreign key relations on two fields that relate back to the same column?

Thanks

Answer (score 5, accepted):

When setting the properties on the relations, set `UseDefaultRoleNames` to No, then give each relation a unique `Role`.

Answer (score 1):

If you add a relation Field, you must add as a foreignkey-field. It also add automatically a field in your table. Then the BP Error must be solved.